# Django administration using pycharm

Tags: python, django, django-admin, pycharm

I started learning Django and I followed the instructions in this page-[jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html), and I got to the "Launching the admin site" section. when I entered to the administration page(127.0.0.1:8000/admin) it asked for username and password, and I don't have one. what to do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a super user, you are asked about this the first time you run the `syncdb` command. 
if you didn't create at that time you can do it later using the command(based on the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)) :

```
django-admin createsuperuser
```

Comment: when I do it, its print:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_environ'

Comment: where did you run it? did you use the manage.py shell(available on the Pycharm tools)?

Comment: or, from a terminal, you can run 'python manage.py createsuperuser'

Comment: when press ctrl+alt+r ("Enter Manage.py task name") and enter to createsuperuser, it ask me for-email, password and username. and when I enter it print-"Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'setup_environ"

Comment: it depends from your project settings, please check in Pycharm settings the current working directory

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have one. The credentials are the ones you enter when running `./manage.py syncdb`. You are asked for `username` and `password`